# How to implement "partial match" in couchdb query

Tags: couchdb

I have a Couchdb that stores documents each of each has a prefix field. Prefixes are unique so they can actually be used as IDs

Say:

```
_id=1 {prefix="AAABBBCCC", ...}
_id=2 {prefix="AAABBBDDD", ...}
_id=3 {prefix="AAABBE", ...}
_id=4 {prefix="AAAFF", ...}
```

I need to query these documents retrieving an appropriate document (always one full match on the prefix) using a key that is longer but completly matches the prefix. Prefix length varies, key length is constant.

```
query_key = AAABBBCCC123 => _id1
query_key = AAABBBDDD456 => _id2
query_key = AAABBEEEEEEE => _id3
query_key = AAABxxxxxxxx => Null
```

Any idea how can this be done in Couch?

Comment: What if there is both `AAABBBCCC` and `AAABBBCCC12` and you query for `AAABBBCCC123`. Which one is the right answer? Or is that situation impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a view emitting `doc.prefix`. Then query **descending** with `startkey` set to your query key with `limit=1`. The resulting prefix *might* be yours but you have to confirm.

You can either confirm the prefix in the client, or with a `_list` function. A `_list` function probably does not help with performance so I would consider doing it in the client, **unless** you have many clients in many languages, and you can standardize on a single URL to query with the same output.

Comment: Oh wow, I just saw your comment with the same technique. Sorry.

Comment: I will give you the point though - did not know about the _list, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *map* function should look like this

```js
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.prefix, doc);
}
```

and you should search for documents with the substring function in the key.

Like this:

```
_design/doc/_view/viewname?key=QUERY_KEY.substring(0, FIXED_KEY_LENGTH)
```

Comment: Not sure about substring, anyway I'll never know FIXED_KEY_LENGTH in advance ...  I got it working through .../_view/QUERY_NAME?startkey="query_key"&descending=true&limit=1 this gives me the last prefix that would have matched, I just need to verify if the prefix is actually contained in the query_key (client-side for the moment).